# Docker,AWS-EKS : Docker-build command, Davfs mount not working, no free coda device to mount

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am working on mounting a `DAVFS` volume inside `docker` container.

Many documents suggest to use `privileged run` command... But I am trying to build the `docker` image with it.

I am getting error:

> no free coda device available.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am using `AWS EKS` to deploy this image. If there is an option to do this with `EKS`, that answer is also acceptable.

DockerFile :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y fuse davfs2 ca-certificates
RUN mkdir /mnt/ftp/
ARG WEB_DAV_URL=DAVFS_URL
RUN echo "DAVFS_URL DAVFS_USERNAME DAVFS_PASSWORD" >> /etc/davfs2/secrets
RUN mount.davfs $WEB_DAV_URL /mnt/

CMD service php7.2-fpm restart && cd /etc/apache2/ && apachectl -d /etc/apache2 -e info -DFOREGROUND
```

Error log :

```
mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse
mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse failed
mount.davfs: waiting for /dev/fuse to be created
mount.davfs: can't open fuse device
mount.davfs: trying coda kernel file system
mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount
```

Note : I need something for docker build, not for docker run... As I am using EKS, docker run is not applicable... :-) There is way to do this via Docker run to add CAP_ADD.

Answer (score -1):

you can use PersistentVolume in your pod while launching it. you need to check for volume plugin which support DAVFS. and to add Capabilities to your pod you can use securityContext module in your pods. refer to below link:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: Can u give an example? Like I said, it's an FTP server . U can use any public FTP server for this approach